# Passing object by value, edit the object and send it back

Tags: c#

When I was building a simple implementation of a binary search tree I came across something that I dont' understand. I'm passing an object as a parameter, editing that object and returning that object. But it hasn' t changed after it's returned.

Here's the responsible method; (with colors for readability: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RenR.png))

```
        public BinarySearchTree Remove(Node current, int value)
    {

        if (value < current.Data)
        {
            return Remove(current.leftLeaf, value);
        }
        else if (value > current.Data)
        {
            return Remove(current.rightLeaf, value);
        }
        else {

            if (current.leftLeaf == null && current.rightLeaf == null) // no children
            {
                current = null;
                return this;
            }
            else if (current.leftLeaf == null) //No left child 
            {
                current = current.rightLeaf;
                return this;
            }
            else if (current.rightLeaf == null) //No right child 
            {
                current = current.leftLeaf;
                return this;
            }

            else  //Has both child nodes
            {
                Node min = FindMin(current.rightLeaf);
                current.Data = min.Data;
                Remove(current.rightLeaf, min.Data);
                return this;
            }
        }

    }
```

and method calling:

```
        BinarySearchTree b = new BinarySearchTree();

        b.Insert(1);
        b.Insert(6);
        b.Insert(2);
        b.Insert(4);
        b.Insert(5);
        b.Insert(3);

        b = b.Remove(b.Root, 1);
        b = b.Remove(b.Root, 2);
        b = b.Remove(b.Root, 3);
        b = b.Remove(b.Root, 4);

        b.Display();
```

Result: 
1 2 3 4 5 6

Expected result:
5 6

Can someone explain why this code is not behaving as I'm expecting?

Comment: "I'm passing an object as a parameter" - no, you're passing a *reference* as an argument. That *reference* is being passed by value. When you write `current = null;` that doesn't change the value of the caller's variable at all. You should read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are passing reference type by value you are actually copying the reference (pointer) to this object and pass (put on the stack) copy of this reference.

You can modify object properties because two references show one actual object in the heap. But if you will try to modify the copy of the reference it will not cause source reference because your caller method have the original reference.

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by
>   the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you
>   cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot
>   use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it
>   persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the
>   ref or out keyword.

See also ["Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: But haven't I overwritten the original value when doing this: b = b.Remove(b.Root, 1); is it not replacing the value with the new (copied and editted) value?

Comment: @KarsBarendrecht You're working on a wrong assumption. Your issue is on `current = null;`, not on `b.Remove(b.Root, 1)`. You're modifying a local reference, it makes no change to the actual tree

Comment: @KooKiz Thank you, I see where the fault lays now. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the reference 'by reference' not 'by value', so you should be able to replace the pointer with a new one inside the method body.

Try to declare Remove method like this:

```
public BinarySearchTree Remove(ref Node current, int value)
```

... and then use this:

```
var root = b.Root;

b = b.Remove(ref root , 1);
b = b.Remove(ref root , 2);
b = b.Remove(ref root , 3);
b = b.Remove(ref root , 4);

b.Root = root;
```

Comment: It's not allowed to pass an object property by reference, I'm affraid. Thanks for replying, but I'm more interested in why this is happening instead of fixing the code. This was made for educational purposes.

Comment: @KarsBarendrecht then you question is about 2 fundamental concepts of c# language: [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and ["Difference Between Passing a Struct and Passing a Class Reference to a Method"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx).